# Keep footer at bottom of long page with an absolute positioned child

Tags: html, css, position

I have a hero section with an absolute positioned text modal within the background image. I want that text modal to sit in the middle, over the background image no matter how long the text (page) is below the hero image section. I have narrowed down the issue to the CSS I have in place to keep the footer at the bottom of the page, below all the content. If I remove `position: relative` in the body CSS selector then the modal will sit right in the middle of hero section, as it should, but then my footer jumps up to the bottom of the viewport rather than the bottom of all the content on the page.

**How do I keep the footer at the bottom of all the content on the page and keep my text modal in the vertical and horizontal center of the hero section?**

See my Code Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hero-page-jk8rr?file=/src/styles.css

**Footer snippets:**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
.footer-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

**Hero snippets:**

```
.hero-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-media {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.hero-modal {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 60%;
  padding: 3rem 7rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

...

       <div className="hero-container">
          <img
            alt="img"
            src={
              "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ship-form-template.appspot.com/o/public%2Fpexels-%C3%A1kos-szab%C3%B3-440731.jpg?alt=media&token=4261a8f1-cf36-45c5-b566-c5c2fa0dd16c"
            }
            className="hero-media"
          />
          <div className="hero-modal">
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum body text goes here. Lorem ipsum body text goes here.
              Lorem ipsum body text goes here. Lorem ipsum body text goes here.
              Lorem ipsum body text goes here. Lorem ipsum body text goes here.
              Lorem ipsum body text goes here. Lorem ipsum body text goes here.
              Lorem ipsum body text goes here. Lorem ipsum body text goes here.
            </p>
            <button>CTA Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/hero-page-forked-4mj3q?file=/src/styles.css

As you can see I removed the `position: relative` in the body tag because that makes the modal sit in the very middle of the page. You already got that right : )

Now because that is removed you don't need the `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` in the footer wrapper anymore because it will stay at the bottom of the page as it's the last element in html order. If you leave it tho it will position itself at the bottom of the loaded screen thats why it bugs somewhere in the middle.

The footer will not be at the very bottom just now because of the `padding-bottom: 2.5rem;` in the body tag. Remove that too and it should work just fine!

Comment: Makes sense, but I adjusted my codesandbox to go to another page to show you what happens to the footer when you make your change. I want the footer to remain at the bottom of the page always!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hero-page-forked-ffcsp?file=/src/styles.css

I forgot to mention that I removed the `padding-bottom: 2.5rem;` in the body too

Comment: Gotcha, still doesn't change my comment's outcome tho. I need the footer at the bottom of the page on every page.

Comment: my bad didn't notice the second page had content. so basically you're just missing a `position: relative;` in the hero-container and remove the `padding-bottom: 2.5rem;` in the body. Let everything else remain like before my changes.